# Nested system folder in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

The Yahoo server blipped when I was creating a custom folder in Thunderbird and somehow the folder got corrupted. It also moved the system Draft folder underneath the corrupted folder, which is nested inside the Inbox. I can't move the system Draft folder out of the corrupted folder & I can't move the corrupted folder out of the Inbox. I have tried everything I can find on this issue, and nothing has worked.

Can someone please help me move the system Draft folder back where it belongs? I want to get rid of this corrupted folder, but Yahoo support says I have to move the system Draft folder out before I can do that. And they won't tell me HOW to do it. They only suggested I use Thunderbird to do it because I couldn't see the Draft folder in Mail on my Iphone or in Yahoo.

I can't setup a new email account right now (would love to get off Yahoo) for personal reasons, so please be kind & dumb it down for me. Any help would be very greatly appreciated!

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Can you simply grab the folder and drag to a higher level?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Drafts` is a special folder, I do not think that Thunderbird will allow the user to move it around directly within the folder pane. However, it *may* be possible to move it by going into `Edit > Account Settings > $GmailAccount > Copies and Folders`. Once there, under the "Drafts and Templates" section, under the "Keep draft messages in" section, choose where you would like the `Drafts` folder to go.

[image: screenshot of account settings area of Thunderbird showing Drafts and Templates subsection]

In theory, it may currently be in `Other`, and underneath the `ZZ - Corrupt Yahoo...` folder. You should be able to choose a different spot for it, or choose the default `"Drafts" folder on` option with the Yahoo account selected.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded, I am very grateful!!! I resolved the issue last night with a TB add-in that let me flatten the folder tree. The Draft folder is back where it belongs & the corrupted folder has been deleted. All my devices that have Yahoo on them are synced now. No more hidden folder or system folder out of place - yeah!!! Thank you again for your help!!!